# Maven checkstyle plugin - check goal cannot find configuration file

Tags: maven, checkstyle

I have been unable to use the checkstyle check goal.  I'm getting the following error:

> Unable to find configuration file at location:
>   ${project.parent.basedir}/.settings/my_checks.xml: Could not find
>   resource '${project.parent.basedir}/.settings/my_checks.xml'.

I get this error when I use the command `mvn checkstyle:check`, but if I run `mvn checkstyle:checkstyle` this configuration file is found and used as expected.

The plugin configuration is shown below.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>           
        </plugin>   

...

    <properties>
        <checkstyle.config.location>${project.parent.basedir}/.settings/my_checks.xml</checkstyle.config.location>         
    </properties>
```

Any suggestions?  Why would the checkstyle goal work but not the check goal?

Edit: Upon further review I have learned that ${project.parent.basedir} does not resolve when running the check goal.  It does resolve when calling the checkstyle goal.  Still looking for suggestions / workarounds...

Comment: this just happened to me. The reason was that I updated the version number in the main pom.xml, but forgot to update it in the pom files of the modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround has been to move away from using the ${project.parent.basedir} variable and to use relative paths.  This works in my case because all my modules are parallel directories.

```
 <checkstyle.config.location>../parent/.settings/my_checks.xml</checkstyle.config.location>
```